# How to trigger a "win" event when two players are standing on two pressure plates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making a  2d unity game where i have two players in different rooms. You control both players at the same time and both need to reach a goal/area to finish the level.

My problem is that when one player touched the area a certain value is set true but the player doesnt need to stand on the area anymore to finish the level. I want it that both players have to stand in the area at the same time to finish a level.

If anyone knows how to do that i would be thankful if you share it with me.
If u guys need some code i can add it .

both players have the same script but the goals have different scripts(But it doesnt have to be . i thought it may be easier with that)
And i am working with c#

Comment: Some code would be nice and easier to help. If I understand you correctly, change the value from bool to int and increment/decrement that value when player enter/leave the area. When both players enter, then the value is equal to 2 - and then you should finish the level.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved it with the OnTriggerExit function which i didnt know existed. I kinda feel dumb but now it works.

Comment: Do not add words like "solved" to the question title. If your question has been answered, use the accept button (checkmark) next to the question that answers the question best. If no answer answers your question but you have found a solution yourself, post your own answer to your question and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine this behaviour either by using [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) or [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) along with [`OnTriggerExit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit2D.html) or [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit2D.html). It can look something like:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        // currently touching a plate   
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        // no longer touching a plate   
    }
}
```

Swapping the bool in either state should give you the outcome you desire. You can tweak this to your specific use quite easily. Let me know if you have questions.